# Start another batch file with multiple parameters with the start command?

Tags: batch-file, call, self-updating

Is it possible to start another batch file and pass along multiple parameters with spaces, using the start command?

Here is how my program currently works:

main program starts > sees its outdated > calls updater (data1.exe) > updater copies new version over > **It tries to delete the old version, but it can't. The old version is still marked as being used, from when it called the updater.**

That's why the call command won't work. Do I need to use start then? How would that work?

This was the original line of code... the one that calls the updater and passes the variables along:

```
call "%dirofbatch%data1.exe" "%downloc%" "%dirofbatch%" "%lver%" "%lget%"
```

I'm stumped.

EDIT: I should mention that "data1.exe" is just an exe'd batch file.

Comment: Do you want to delete a running program ('main program')? You should show more code from your batch. what is `%dirofbatch%` exactly?

Comment: 1. Yes, I want to use the updated version of the main program and delete the old version, which is apparently still running. 2. The %dirofbatch% is essentially, "%~dp0".

Comment: Windows doesn't allow to delete running apps.

Comment: That's why i'm asking if the 'start' command would work instead. The start command starts the specified program in a separate window. So how would I pass those 4 variables to the updater?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to read parameters in a batch file:

1. caller batch

   ```
   start "" "%dirofbatch%data1.exe" "%downloc%" "%dirofbatch%" "%lver%" "%lget%"
   ```
2. called batch

   ```
   set "parm1=%~1"
   set "parm2=%~2"
   set "parm3=%~3"
   set "parm4=%~4"
   echo %parm1% %parm2% %parm3% %parm4%
   ```

Comment: I think you may be a bit confused :P

Comment: I can't use the call command because it keeps the caller program alive... and because the caller program is still alive, i can't delete it. I need to know how to pass variables to the 2nd batch file (data1.exe) with the START command, NOT the CALL command, so that the updater runs in a separate window.